# Alternative(faster) to sshfs to connect to a local vm

Tags: virtualization, sshfs, webstorm

I am currently using sshfs to connect to a local vm running in virt manager.

However when using this mounted filesystem with webstorm (it gives a warning external file changes may be slow) things run quite slow. Is there a better way to run this mount to get the performance I need?

I heard there is a way run some sort of ntfs server in the vm but not sure about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean "NFS"... not NTFS.

First, yes NFS is faster... but also has some drawbacks.  It is much more difficult to securely manage NFS shares than using sshfs.  Additionally, NFS has no encryption by-default which puts much less load on your CPU.  You can tunnel NFS traffic through ssh and you'll still see performance improvements over sshfs.  NFS is also implemented in the kernel-space, whereas sshfs is in user-space.  (fuse)

Comment: thanks, but how is it more difficult for secruity?

Comment: You would need to wrap NFS traffic into a ssh tunnel.  That always makes things more difficult.  :)  Other than that, it relies on file-system level permissions.  (make sure user and group IDs match on both sides)

Comment: thanks, do you know what yum repo I need for the nfs-utils package?http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/set-up-easy-file-sharing-with-nfs-on-linux/#.